# B2C ClaimsTransformation AddItemToStringCollection / StringJoin

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to do an OutputClaimsTransformation to map azure ad field values to a SAML attribute. Therefore I created some claims and ClaimsTransformations.

```
Claim collection of type "StringCollection".
Claim output of type "String".
Claim team of type "String".
```

First I use **AddParameterToStringCollection** to add string "123" to claim *collection*.
Second I use **LookupValue** to map a User ClaimType string to claim *team*. This shall a string like "253" when user attribute "country" matches "UK". Third step is adding the *team* to claimcollection *collection*. Last step is TransformationMethed **StringJoin** to join *collection* to *output* with delimiter "," like "123,253".

This will work great if a mapping exists in step 2. If not, the **AddItemToStringCollection** will add "null" to the collection and the **StringJoin** will result in "123,". Now the last "," has to be removed. Or I need a way to skip the **AddItemToStringCollection** on null value.

My code

```
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="addGeneralToCollection" TransformationMethod="AddParameterToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="collection" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="item" DataType="string" Value="123" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="collection" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="mapCountryToTeam" TransformationMethod="LookupValue">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_country" TransformationClaimType="inputParameterId" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="errorOnFailedLookup" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
          <InputParameter Id="albania" DataType="string" Value="456" />
          <InputParameter Id="algeria" DataType="string" Value="789" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="team" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="joinDefaultToCountryTeam" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="team" TransformationClaimType="item" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="collection" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="collection" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="ConvertTeamCollectionToString" TransformationMethod="StringJoin">
        <InputClaims>
         <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="collection" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter DataType="string" Id="delimiter" Value="," />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="output" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
```

This is working great for all defined countries. But not for those countries which are possible in the custom field list but having no mapping,

Edit:
It is not an error when the mapping is not found. It should just skip this case. The scenario: We have a list of all countries. Half of the countries have a deprecated support team. Now I want to transform the country to a code inside a saml response, so my application know which support is the correct one for that user. Inside application it is represented by an integer. And additionally there is a global support which can be asked by everyone.

So, I want to add the general integer for global team and the integer for country depended team if defined. If not, it should just add general support. But it should not throw an error.

I can solve this by defining the general team to every country in the list. But it would be much nicer to configure the mapping properly. Is there a way to shrink last char, when it is a comma?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution which I can think of based on the implementation is to make the below change in the lookupValue **TransformationMethod**

```
<InputParameter Id="errorOnFailedLookup" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
```

When **errorOnFailedLookup** input parameter is set to **true** , the LookupValue claims transformation is always executed from a validation technical profile that is called by a self-asserted technical profile, or a DisplayControl.
The **LookupNotFound** metadata of a self-asserted technical profile controls the error message that is presented to the user.

**Sample SelfAsserted Technical Profile:**

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="CountryValue">
                <DisplayName>Country Value</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    ......
                    <Item Key="LookupNotFound">Country Not Found</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                   ....
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="output" />                       
                </OutputClaims>
                <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Country-Transformation" />
                </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

**Technical Profile for Claims Tranformation:**

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="Country-Transformation">
                <DisplayName>Country</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="output" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="addGeneralToCollection" />
<OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="mapCountryToTeam" />
<OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="joinDefaultToCountryTeam" />
<OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ConvertTeamCollectionToString" />
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: It is not an error when the mapping is not found. It should just skip this case. The scenario: We have a list of all countries. Half of the countries have a deprecated support team. Now I want to transform the country to a code inside a saml response, so my application know which support is the correct one for that user. Inside application it is represented by an integer. And additionally there is a global support which can be asked by everyone.